# convert struct to objective c array or class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, c, struct

I m new for IOS. I have some source code for OS X and java. I was trying to convert to IOS. 
In OS X, I have the following.

```
struct _NoteData {
    int number;             /** The Midi note number, used to determine the color */
    WhiteNote *whitenote;   /** The white note location to draw */
    NoteDuration duration;  /** The duration of the note */
    BOOL leftside;          /** Whether to draw note to the left or right of the stem */
    int accid;              /** Used to create the AccidSymbols for the chord */
};
typedef struct _NoteData NoteData;

@interface ChordSymbol : NSObject <MusicSymbol> {

    _NoteData notedata[20];/** The notes to draw */

}
```

`_NoteData` is like an array and class here.  `number`, `whitenote`,`duration`..are instance variable for _noteData.

I was trying to change struct to objective c class:

```
@interface  _NoteData:NSObject{
    @property NSInteger number_color;       
   @property WhiteNote *whitenote;   
   @property NoteDuration duration;  
   @property BOOL leftside;          
   @property NSInteger accid;    
  };
    @interface ChordSymbol : NSObject <MusicSymbol> {

    _NoteData notedata[20];/** The notes to draw */

}
```

In my .m file, it has

```
+(BOOL)notesOverlap:(_NoteData*)notedata withStart:(int)start andEnd:(int)end {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

        if (!notedata[i].leftside) {
           return YES;
       }
   }
return NO;
}
```

`!notedata[i]` throw error `expected method to read array element`. I understand `_NoteData` is a class, not an array. What should I change?

In java:

```
 private NoteData[] notedata;
```

`NoteData` is a class, and `notedata` is an array which store `NoteData`.
Same method in java

```
 private static boolean NotesOverlap(NoteData[] notedata, int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (!notedata[i].leftside) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I feel all I need is to declare an array with `_NoteData` object.  How can I do that?

Comment: _NoteData* notedata <- this is the obvious correction in the first glance. But.. you don't have to modify struct _NoteData for iOS.

Comment: If I donot modify struct _NoteData to objective c class, xcode shows ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs, since whitenote is an objective class. I do not want to use __unsafe_unretained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C is a superset of C, so you can use C struct in Objective-C code. You can keep your code in the first paragraph. You need to move the function declaration in `ChordSymbol` class's header file.

```
+(BOOL)notesOverlap:(NoteData*)notedata withStart:(int)start andEnd:(int)end;
```

In another Objective-C class's implementation file, call the Class function like this.

```
NoteData y[] = {
    { .leftside = YES },
    { .leftside = YES },
    { .leftside = YES },
    { .leftside = YES }
};

BOOL result = [ChordSymbol notesOverlap:y withStart:0 andEnd:3];
NSLog(@"%d",result);
```

*Edit*

You can use `NSArray` for this purpose. You create an array and populate its data with `NoteData` objects.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
NoteData *data1 = [[NoteData alloc] init];
data1.number_color = 1;
[array addObject:data1];
```

Then you should change `(_NoteData*)notedata` to `(NSArray*)array`, and it should work.

Comment: the problem of first paragraph is that whitenote is an objective c class, so I will get  ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs. I donot want to manually manage the memory, so I am trying to convert it to an objective c class.

Comment: That's the way to go, otherwise you have to make whitenote also a struct, now you can convert whitenote and NoteData to NSObject objects.